# Manager for results of physical simulations

Tags: simulations, software, data-analysis

I have quite a general question. I'm phd student in the field of plasma physics, our team has developed a numerical simulation of a diagnostic method in plasma (langmuir probes), written in fortran. So far, so good. I'm spending now a lot of time by running the code and comparing results. I have several versions of the code and there are about 15 physical parameters for the code. At the beginning, I always copied the code to a folder, run it and wait for results and then process then by hand. When I had several hundreds folders I realized that this is not the right way...

Therefore, I wrote a script (main parts are written in bash, but it calls many functions written in python) that can take the config file with all parameters, generate a unique directory from these parametres, run the code (even on remote machines via ssh) in that folder and store all parameters whit the directory into database (this is really great, since I can later refer to a simulation by it's primary key). Moreover, the script is checking the simulation while it's running and sends me results to my mailbox, since I never now how long does it take to reach the steady-state which is what I need. When I decide that the simulation has reached the stedy-state, I kill the process, again, via the script. The script then takes all results and make an ipython notebook with all plots and numbers I need and push it to my ipython server.

Sounds great, but there are many bottlenecks (I don't want to bother you with details) and, as it is written in bash, it is really hard to do any changes. I'm now thinking about writing it from scratch again, this time in pure Python. You can probably imagine that this is not entirely trivial task.

However, I think that this is exactly what every physicist dealing with numerical simulations MUST want. So, does anybody know about any library or package that has similar functionality, or have you ever wrote something similar and share with me you experience?

I've spent a lot time googling around but found nothing...

I will probably use Python with SqlAlchemy for db, paramiko for copying over ssh and running remote commands, pandas and numpy for reading and processing results from files and thinking about flask and matplotlib with mpld3 for interactive webpages to see and compare results.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about scientific computing problems and belongs on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You know, as projects scale up the work required to set up the software pipeline becomes comparable to the work needed to write the simulation code/design the telescope/build the particle collider. And alas these are usually quite specialized; I'm not aware of any "pipeline infrastructures" out there.

Comment: Tanks for comments. I will post it on scicomp.stackexchange.com.